# Where are panda antivirus exclusion config files stored?

Tags: anti-virus

I know should be easy to find having panda installed in one's computer, but my question isn't about general configuration, but more specifically about where are the files that hold the "virus" exclusion list.

EDIT: I see my question is not clear enough, so just to clarify: With virus exclusion I mean the list of files that should not be scanned for viruses.

Comment: Do you mean the list of files/directories to not scan for viruses, or the list of viruses to not attempt to detect?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant

Comment: @XaitormanX Which of the two did you mean? That wasn't a yes or no question.

Comment: So you want to know what files Panda stores its configuration in, specifically, the whitelisted or excluded files?

You do NOT need to know where in the Panda program interface this information is located.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to know what files Panda stores its whitelist configuration in.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration information for Panda Antivirus is probably stored inside the Registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Panda Software\

If the configuration is stored in flat files, these files will likely be encrypted to prevent unauthorized modification.

Knowing what you're trying to do with this information will help us better determine the best way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a computer which uses deep freeze but I forgot the password, so I am temporarily using an external hard drive to boot windows from it and change the files I wan't, but this way I can't add exceptions. So i thought that maybe I could boot normally, configure panda, and then transfer the modified config files to a hard drive. Then boot from an external drive and transfer those modified config files back, so that panda doesn't check for those. It's a bit of a mess to use the computer like that, but I don't want to format yet